# Replace characters in column names gsub

Tags: r, gsub

I am reading in a bunch of CSVs that have stuff like "sales - thousands" in the title and come into R as "sales...thousands". I'd like to use a regular expression (or other simple method) to clean these up.

I can't figure out why this doesn't work:

```
#mock data
  a <- data.frame(this.is.fine = letters[1:5],
                  this...one...isnt = LETTERS[1:5])

#column names
  colnames(a)
  # [1] "this.is.fine"  "this...one...isnt"

#function to remove multiple spaces
  colClean <- function(x){
    colnames(x) <- gsub("\\.\\.+", ".", colnames(x))
  }

#run function
  colClean(a)

#names go unaffected
  colnames(a)
  # [1] "this.is.fine"  "this...one...isnt"
```

but this code does:

```
#direct change to names
  colnames(a) <- gsub("\\.\\.+", ".", colnames(a))

#new names
  colnames(a)
  # [1] "this.is.fine"  "this.one.isnt"
```

Note that I'm fine leaving one period between words when that occurs.

Thank you.

Comment: Replacement occurs locally, inside the function, not globally.  If you `return(x)` on the last line of the function, you will get the updated data frame.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Can you type out the function as it needs to be written? I tried putting ```return(x)``` into the code and am not getting the results I am expecting. I can get it to print out the column names or print out a dataframe with the new column names, but neither attempt has actually changed the data frame in the global environment.

Comment: you also need to either use updated data frame to override existing data frame, or assign to new variable. The original data frame will not be changed by function itself even you did `return(x)`.

Comment: Define `colClean <- function(x){ colnames(x) <- gsub("\\.\\.+", ".", colnames(x)); x }` and then do `a <- colClean(a)` to update `a`

Comment: d'oh, that last step with the assignment! Clearly the result of a long week. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Rich Scriven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3063910/rich-scriven) had the answer:

Define

```
colClean <- function(x){ colnames(x) <- gsub("\\.\\.+", ".", colnames(x)); x }
```

and then do

```
a <- colClean(a)
```

to update a

Answer (score 41):

```
names(a) <- gsub(x = names(a), pattern = "\\.", replacement = "#")
```

you can use `gsub` function to replace `.` with another special character like `#`.

Comment: I had to repalce 'names' with 'colnames' or use 'fixed=T'  to not to repalce the whole column name.