# How to rename columns by substituting suffix in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have several column names in my dataset (eat10.18) that have the suffix "_10p." I'd like to change that suffix to be "_p_10" but preserve the rest of the variable name. I only want this to affect columns that end in the exact string "_10p." I cannot figure out how to make this work with rename_with(). Can anyone help? Faux data below:

```
eat10.18 <- data.frame(id = c(1000, 1001, 1002),
eat_10 = c(2, 4, 1),
eat_10p = c(1, 2, 3),
run_10p = c(1, 1, 2))
```

In the above example, the variables "id" and "eat_10" would remain the same, but "eat_10p" and "run_10p" would become "eat_p_10" and "run_p_10"

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

eat10.18 %>%
  rename_with(~str_replace(.,'_10p$', '_p_10'))

    id eat_10 eat_p_10 run_p_10
1 1000      2        1        1
2 1001      4        2        1
3 1002      1        3        2
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `gsub` and referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670918/replace-characters-in-column-names-gsub).

`names(eat10.18) <- gsub(x = names(eat10.18), pattern = "_10p", replacement = "_p_10")`

**Result**

| id | eat_10 | eat_p_10 | run_p_10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1001 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 1002 | 1 | 3 | 2 |